# Rails - How to add more fields for filter in searchkick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, where-clause

In rails, I am using `searchkick` gem for search. When I am adding more fields for where clause then returning zero results.

Actually search is working for below method(User.rb),

```
searchkick word_start: [:name]

def initialize(name, limit = User::SUGGESTION_LIMIT, page = nil)
  @name = name
  @limit = limit
  @page = page
  @per_page = limit.to_i
end

query = {
    match: :word_start,
    fields: [{ emails: "exact" }, "name^5"],
    misspellings: { prefix_length: 2 },
    load: false
}

User.search(name, query).records
```

When I add condition like `where: {active: false, inactive: true, deleted_at: nil}` it returns no data.

```
query = {
    match: :word_start,
    where: {active: false, inactive: true, deleted_at: nil},
    fields: [{ emails: "exact"}, "name^5"],
    misspellings: { prefix_length: 2 },
    load: false
}
```

Is there any mistake in above `where` condition? Please help me to solve this issue. I am using this gem for the first time.

Comment: does `deleted_at: nil` means `inactive: true` here ?

Comment: No. If account is deleted then `deleted_at is not NULL` and `inactive: true`. If account is active then `deleted_at is NULL` and `inactive: false`.

Comment: so you're trying to get records with `inactive: true` and `deleted_at: nil`. this seems pretty opposite condition. I think it should be inactive true and deleted_at is not nil. and if you're looking for active records then it should be inactive false and deleted_at is nil. let me know if I am understanding it wrong

Comment: Yes. You are right. If I try with `where: {inactive: false, deleted_at: nil}` then I am getting an error like `Searchkick::InvalidQueryError ([400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to create query: {\n  \"bool\" ...`

Comment: can you show the full exception ?

Comment: Now I am trying with string field instead of boolean. So I have raised separate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47992634/rails-how-to-filter-a-string-field-in-searchkick

Comment: Refer this for the answer- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47977917/rails-how-to-add-more-fields-for-filter-in-searchkick

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the fields used in the `where` clause are indexed differently.
You have to define those fields as `filterable`:

```
searchkick word_start: [:name], filterable: [:active, :inactive, :deleted_at]
```

This should work.

BTW: You don't need both "active" and "inactive" attributes. If the "active" attribute is false, you know it is inactive.

Comment: Again same zero results. Also I have tried by `reindex()` the model, but same issue.