# Rails - How to filter a string field in searchkick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, where-clause

In rails, I am using `searchkick` gem for search. I need to add one string field called `status` for filter. How can I add to this plugin?

Already I have raised one question regarding this issue [Rails - How to add more fields for filter in searchkick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47977917/rails-how-to-add-more-fields-for-filter-in-searchkick)

Now I am trying with string field instead of boolean still search is not working. Please help me regarding the same.

I have added a condition like `where: {status: 'approved'}`, as per this condition I should get only active users(not 'deleted' users). Right now no search data is displaying.

```
searchkick word_start: [:name]

def initialize(name, limit = User::SUGGESTION_LIMIT, page = nil)
  @name = name
  @limit = limit
  @page = page
  @per_page = limit.to_i
end

query = {
  match: :word_start,
  where: {status: 'approved'},
  fields: [{ emails: "exact" }, "name^5"],
  misspellings: { prefix_length: 2 },
  load: false
}

User.search(name, query).records
```

Also I have tried by adding filterable like `searchkick word_start: [:name], filterable: [:status]`

Server log is,

```
Processing by UsersController#search as JSON
Parameters: {"query"=>"sal"}
ETHON: Libcurl initialized
ETHON: performed EASY 
effective_url=http://elastic:changeme@14.127.18.141:9200/users-some_index-en/_search response_code=200 return_code=ok total_time=0.498938
User Search (589.3ms)  curl http://14.127.18.141:9200/users-some_index-en/_search?pretty -d '{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"dis_max":{"queries":[{"match":{"emails.true":{"query":"sal","boost":10,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_autocomplete_search"}}},{"match":{"emails.true":{"query":"sal","boost":1,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_autocomplete_search","fuzziness":1,"prefix_length":2,"max_expansions":3,"fuzzy_transpositions":true}}},{"bool":{"must":{"bool":{"should":[{"match":{"name.word_start":{"query":"sal","boost":50.0,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_word_search"}}},{"match":{"name.word_start":{"query":"sal","boost":5.0,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_word_search","fuzziness":1,"prefix_length":2,"max_expansions":3,"fuzzy_transpositions":true}}}]}},"should":{"match":{"name.analyzed":{"query":"sal","boost":50.0,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_word_search"}}}}}]}},"filter":[{"term":{"status":"approved"}}]}},"size":5,"from":0,"timeout":"11s"}'
User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
ETHON: performed EASY effective_url=http://elastic:changeme@14.127.18.141:9200/entities-some_index-en/_search response_code=200 return_code=ok total_time=0.251783
```

Comment: The snippet of code you added isn't enough for us to understand what you're trying. Add more code.

Comment: Question has been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `scope :search_import` based on your condition and modify `should_index?` method like,

```
def should_index?
  User.search_import
end
```

After this changes, call reindex separately `after_update` of any data